# How can I pause all the other threads in Python?

Tags: python, celery

I'm making a `"python debug mapper"` that shows a `'snapshot'` of current python execution

Currently, I need to know a way to `pause every other threads` so that the `'capture'` won't happen while other threads are running.

Are there any way to do:

- PauseOtherThreads();
- ResumeOtherThreads();

Thanks.

p.s: should I make any modifications to get the code working with Celery and Django?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if you want just to trace one thread while other threads are running or if you want to stop other threads I can think to two solutions. If other threads must run without tracing just make your trace command check the current thread id first and only do the trace operation if the thread is the one you are interested in:

```
def dotrace():
    if tracing and threading.current_thread() == the_traced_thread:
        ... do the tracing ...
```

If instead other threads must stop while one is being traced you can make your tracing operation work as an halt for other threads adding something like:

```
def dotrace():
    while tracing and threading.current_thread() != the_traced_thread:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    if tracing and threading.current_thread() == the_traced_thread:
        ... do the tracing ...
```

Of course only the trace operations will work as an halt in the last case, so other threads may keep running until they finish or they do anything that is traced.

Basically you will only stop other threads that you are monitoring and not all other threads. I'd say this is good because increases the probability that the program will still remain functional (some of the libraries and frameworks you use may need other threads to run for the thread being traced to actually work) but of course YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You could using `sys.setcheckinterval(somebignumber)`

```
setcheckinterval(...)
    setcheckinterval(n)

    Tell the Python interpreter to check for asynchronous events every
    n instructions.  This also affects how often thread switches occur.
```